# read xml using xpath and DOM parser

Tags: java, xml, dom, xpath

I have following sample xml

```
<employee>
  <description>Age:26</description>
  <description>Height:6.0</description>
  <description>Weight:180</description>
  <description>HairColor:Black</description>
</employee>
<employee>
  <description>Degree:BS</description>
  <description>Experience:4 years</description>
  <description>HairColor:Black</description>
</employee>
```

I do not have control over the xml and the elements are optional and it is getting reported by different agencies that are consolidated into one xml. I need to parse it and I am using XPath and DOM parser. I am able to print the Description tags by the following code where nList is list of Employee nodes

```
private static void getChargeDescription(NodeList nList) {
  for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++) {

    //get employee node
    Node nNode = nList.item(i);
    if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
      Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
      NodeList descriptionNodes = eElement.getElementsByTagName("description");
      for(int j = 0; j < descriptionNodes.getLength(); j++) {
        System.out.println(descriptionNodes.item(j).getTextContent());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My question is how to set the property for the following class.

```
public class Employee {
  private List<String> Height;
  private List<String> Weight;
  private List<String> Experience;
  private List<String> HairColor;
  private List<String> Age;
  private List<String> Degree;
  //getters and setters 
}
```

Because the name of the element Description is going to be same and each agency can report different number of Description and there can be same Description across multiple Employee elements. So the only way I could think of is get the text content and identify what kind of information it is. Is there any other way?

Comment: Are age, degree, etc. unique per employee? Seems to me that attributes are single ones, not lists. If not, how many Employee objects will exist?

Comment: Correct those will be list.. will update the post. Since my question was more about an efficient way of getting textcontent did not pay attention to it. All of them will be  list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it seems from your `Employee` object, you know the attributes names (Age, Degree, etc.). You can iterate those names and get all elements containing that attribute using XPath, then construct your Lists

XPath example using `xmllint` command line utility

`xmllint --xpath '//description[starts-with(text(),"Age")]' test.xml`

`<description>Age:26</description>`

The `NodeList descriptionNodes` will contain only the requested attribute, `Age` in the example above. You could have 2 for-loops, the outer for the attribute names and the inner for current NodeList.

Comment: Ok. So what I am doing right now is, I have a list of constants that represents the attributes and I am comparing the text content (Age:26) with the constants and building the list accordingly. With xmlInt it is the same logic but a more cleaner way using the command line utility, correct?

Comment: with this XPath `'//description[starts-with(text(),"Age")]'` you will get all `description`elements with `Age` in the value. You can split the string to get the Age value (26) and store it in `List<String> Age`. I used xmllint to demonstrate the XPath usage since I don't have java code to test that. Will add a note to the answer.